# Problems upgrading to Python 3.3 and setting up Django

Tags: django, linux, debian, python-3.3

I'm new to Linux and am trying to set up Python / Django on my machine!  I installed Python 3.3 from the source file and it was compiled into `/usr/local/bin`. Then I created a symbolic link between `/usr/bin/python` and `/usr/local/bin/python3`, so that whenever I invoke python from the command line it uses the latest version.

Now I am trying to install MySQL Python and I got the following output:

```
apt-get install python-mysqldb

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
python-mysqldb is already the newest version.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  apt-listchanges python-apt
Suggested packages:
  python-glade2 python-gtk2 python-apt-dbg python-vte python-apt-doc
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt-listchanges python-apt
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 142 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/394 kB of archives.
After this operation, 250 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/apt-listchanges", line 28, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?  Or any tips on how to clean up this install (if this one is too broken)?

Comment: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=368695

Answer (score 1):

Re-installing Python (`apt-get install --reinstall python`) should fix your installation issue.

Note that your approach will result in a lot of brokenness. Changing system Python version involves far than just changing symlinks, which is why you should leave it to the distro makers ([see a similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9711/)).

One other fact is that Debian already [packages 3.3](http://packages.qa.debian.org/p/python3.3.html) (currently in Experimental), so rather install that. I just don't know if the system Python modules (e.g. `python-apt`) will work with it. If not, just use 3.2.

One other thing, if you want to use python-mysqldb, you have to stick to Python 2, because it will not run with Python 3. If you insist on Python 3, use `python3-mysql.connector`.